# How to access array linked lists on heap?

Tags: c

I am having a problem accessing an subarray of a node. I have two structs written where one contains the other. I'm not able to access the beyond the first node of the subarray.

```
struct node{
    int distance;
    int destination;
    int weight;
    node *adj;
}; 

struct adjList{
    struct node *node;
    adjList *array;
};// adjList a is made out of an array of "nodes". Essentially each element in the adjList  a should have a pointer to a subarray of "nodes" that i can access.


a=(adjList*) malloc(numOfNodes * sizeof(struct adjList));//allocate space for array of linked lists


for(int j=0; j<numOfNodes; j++){
    array[j].node=malloc(numOfEdges * sizeof(struct node));//allocate space for each linked list in the array
                }


  for(int j=0; j<numOfNodes; j++){
   a[j].node->adj[j]=NULL; //trying to set the "jth's" element of the adjacencylist's "jth" node. This syntax does not work as the compiler wont let me even use it.
      }
```

My whole goal here is to have an array of linked lists. Not sure why this method isnt working.

Comment: please be specific if you use `c` or `c++`. those are two very different languages.

Comment: I am pretty sure you don't allocate the correct memory space for your a-variable. You want to use the sizeof adjList, since you store elements of that type.

Comment: Also you access your node via a[j].node->adj, but you didn't define a value for a[j].node before. It's essentially a pointer to nothing - or in your case, something random, because you used malloc and you didn't zeroed your memory there.

Comment: If you want an array of linked lists, all you need is an array of pointers. There's no need for `struct adjList`. OTOH, if you're trying to make a linked list of linked lists, then that's a different story.

Comment: Where are the definitions of `node` and `adjList?` Unless you are using C++ the tags of struct definitions are not automatically available as type names as well.

Answer (score 1):

To have array of linked list, you need to create an array of pointers to the first node of linked lists.

```
struct node **array = malloc(sizeof(struct node*) * arraySize /* numOfNodes */);
```

Now `array[i]` will be pointing to `ith` linked list.

```
for(int i=0; i<arraySize ; i++){
    struct node *head = NULL;
    /* Allocate nodes for ith linked list */
    for(int j=0; j<numOfNodes; j++) {
        if(0 == j) {
            array[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct node)); //First node of ith linked list
            memset(array[i], 0, sizeof(struct node)); //OR you can use calloc. Required to remove junk pointers in node.
            head = array[i];
        } else {
            head->adj = malloc(sizeof(struct node)); /* Allocate jth node */
            memset(head->adj, 0, sizeof(struct node)); //OR you can use calloc. Required to remove junk pointers in node.
            head = head->adj;
        }
    }
}
```

You can traverse `ith` linked list as below.

```
struct node *head = array[i];
while(head) {
    printf("\ndist %d dest %d weight %d\n", head->distance, head->destination, head->weight);
    head = head->adj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read the man page [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/free.3.html), in particular the calloc() part.

It is not enough to just put a pointer into a struct and assume that magically there will be an array. You have to reserve memory for it by using the functions described in that man page. And more importantly you have to `free()` the reserved memory, when you don't need it anymore.

Also you should consider making the length of your array part of your struct.
Like so:

```
struct node{
    int distance;
    int destination;
    int weight;
    node *adj;
    size_t adj_count;
}; 

struct adjList{
    struct node *node;
    size_t node_count;
    adjList *next; // I renamed this member to next,
                   // which makes it more clear that this is a linked list
};
```

*EDIT:* After you edited your question, there is suddenly a malloc(), but it is most certainly wrong. Or your naming of your data structures is very misleading.